# webView not loading scorm content

Tags: android, webview, scorm, lms

I have to load scorm content in my WebView.but failed load content and webview throws an error alert saying.. "unable to acquire LMs api content may not play properly and results may not be recorded"
below is my code

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());    
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl(remoteUrl);
```

please tell me if have any idea how to solve this.
Thanks

Comment: Does `remoteUrl` point at a URL that is a SCORM player? When the content is loaded it will check the parent window to look for the SCORM RunTime API which is a JavaScript object that implements the SCORM interface the content uses to track learner information. That player then generally loads the actual instructional content.